# How do I get email notification when files are added to Amazon S3 using AWS Lambda (Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, notifications

How do I get email notification when files are added to Amazon S3 using AWS Lambda? I want to do the scripting using Python. And I also want to read the file header (as a dictionary) from the CSV files getting uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think anyone is going to write any code for you here unless you need some specific help with some error you're coming across but here's what I think you should look at:

1. Check out AWS EventBridge. I believe there is an event which is emitted there with a source of `aws.s3` and in the details it has `eventName: PutObject`.
2. Write a Lambda function that accepts the above event from AWS EventBridge and sends you an email perhaps via AWS SNS or AWS SES.
3. Add an EventBridge rule to listen to the S3 `PutObject` event with a target of your Lambda function.

There is actually an example of what you're looking for at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-dynamic-amazon-s3-event-handling-with-amazon-eventbridge/

Comment: I'm not sure why someone voted this down? If this isn't going to work then please feel free to add a comment with why!